# Cant configure Apache with Passenger + Rails

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I am only beginner and try to understand how to configure apach web-server for my RubyOnRails app. I have linux, installed apache2, passenger and apache2-module for passenger. While installing i got text like this

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/rubys/.rvm/.../ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/rubys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.8
PassengerRuby /home/rubys/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby
```

I need add this to my apache config file, so, i use

```
$ apachectl -V | grep HTTPD_ROOT
$ apachectl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```

file, which i need is here

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

my rails app is here

```
/home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot
```

Also i have file in /etc/apache2/ports.conf with text like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen80
```

What I have to copy to my **apache2.conf**? and where i have to add this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName depot.yourhost.com
   DocumentRoot /home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot
   <Directory /home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You're not really clear on what is being asked. You might want to clear up exactly what problem you're having and how we can help.

Comment: In which file I need to add: <VirtualHost *:80> ... </VirtualHost>? In apache2.conf? And In which file add passenger routes?

Comment: Can I write: "ServerName localhost"?

Comment: You are way out of your depth here @AlexKurmaev - You need to spend some quality time with an Apache tutorial, or alternatively [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) and understand the configuration files before you start mucking about with Passenger. You're trying to build a skyscraper, but you haven't learned how to use a hammer yet...

Comment: I dont think so voretaq7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DocumentRoot` must be set to the `public` directory of your Rails app.

For instance (it seems you're trying out the demo from the Rails book):

```
   DocumentRoot /home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot/public
```

Comment: Yes it is. I decided my problem with creating new file in /etc/apache2/sites-available' with <VirtualHost *:80>...</VirtualHost *:80> and using 'RailsEnv development' there.